# ext_emconf.php broken after composer install (EXT: jh_captcha)

Tags: typo3

When I download the extension as ZIP file the ext_emconf.php file looks fine, but when I install the extension with composer `"typo3-ter/jh-captcha": "1.3.0"` the ext_emconf.php is broken and lets the extensionmanager crash.

Here are both files: https://gist.github.com/misterboe/5386df69c7ea70c6538de5fd3a52e70f

The original extension has no composer.json file so this must be auto generated.

The problem is the empty `'' => '',` dependencie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually isn't related to the composer installers, but is due to a (now already fixed) error in TER, which caused generating corrupted ext_emconf information in the t3x extension archive. The composer installers rely on this information and extract them to a (faulty) ext_emconf.php.

You could contact the extension author and tell him to remove and then re-upload this extension version, which will make the error go away.

Alternatively the author could upload a version 1.3.1.

If you then change your version constraint from "1.3.0" to "~1.3.1", which is recommended anyway, composer will download the fixed extension archive.